# Method Calling Issues Java

Tags: java

So i'm trying to call a method displayBoard in java that displays the boardgame once the user enters in a number initially in the main method. I'm unable to call this method. Does anyone see where i'm going wrong or how do i fix this? Thanks.

```
public static void displayBoard(int [] board, boolean showItem)
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("_");
    for (int val : board){
        switch(codes){
        case 2:
        System.out.print("x");
        break;
        case 3:
        System.out.print(" ");
        break;
        case 4:
        System.out.print(showItem ? "Y" : " ");
        break;
    }
    System.out.print("_");
} //for
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
}//display

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int guess = 0;
    int userInput = promptForInt("Length Of board");
    int [] numbers = new int[userInput];
    int randomlocs = new Random().nextInt(userInput);
    int val;
    int display = displayBoard(board [], boolean showItem) // doesnt work?
    boolean showItem = false;


    while(! showItem)
    {
        val = promptForInt("Try Again!");
        if(guess == randomlocation)
        {
            System.out.println("Found it!");
            showItem = true;
        }
        else if(guess != randomlocs)
        System.out.print(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

You must pass values to the method call. Right now, you are passing *declarations* to the method, which isn't proper Java syntax

**How To Fix**

First, declare your `showItem` boolean before you call the method so you have a `boolean` to pass to the method. It should look like this:

```
boolean showItem = false;
int display = displayBoard(numbers, showItem)
```

This will pass the vakues stored in your `numbers` and `showItem` variables. We know the values stored in these specific variables (`numbers` and `showItem`) should be passed in due to the method's parameter names.

The statements leading up to that method call should look like this:

```
int userInput = promptForInt("Length Of board");
int [] numbers = new int[userInput];
boolean showItem = false;
int display = displayBoard(board [], boolean showItem);

int randomlocs = new Random().nextInt(userInput); //since this isn't used before the method call, it should be declared below it
int guess = 0; //same with this
int val; //and this
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand where i'm going wrong now. I'm trying this at the moment and its saying "incompatable types".

Comment: @Zynk That is because `displayBoard` is a `void` method, which does not return a value. It should either be an `int` method, which returns an integer, or you shouldn't be initializing a variable with it, like you are with `int display = displayBoard(int[], boolean)`. The way I see it, you don't need the `int display` variable

Comment: Ah i see, it doesnt look like i need it then but when I run the execute the program the board doesn't display when the user is promoted for a value in promptForInt which is why I thought I needed it.
Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Zynk No problem! :) Don't forget to mark as *accepted answer* if it fixed your problem, to let others know how to fix it